# Remove posts from a specific category from homepages

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

How to I can remove posts from a specific category from homepages in wordpress?
I want to do it by category's name or id or ...

I use the loop to get my posts like these:

```
if (!have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
```

thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this function, there's no need to know what your cat-id is, just use the category-slug:

```
function exclude_category($query) {
if ( $query->is_front_page ) {
    $category_ID1 = get_cat_id(category_slugA);
    $category_ID2 = get_cat_id(category_slugB);
    $query->set('cat',"-$category_ID1 -$category_ID2");
} return $query;
} add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using this plugin: wordpress.org/extend/plugins/front-page-excluded-categories You might also try adding this code to your 'functions.php':

```
<?php function excludeCat($query) { if ( $query->is_home ) { $query->set('cat', '-3,-5,-23'); }  return $query; } add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'excludeCat'); ?>
```

where -3, -5 and -23 are the category ids you want to remove.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [Advanced Category Excluder](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-category-excluder/). Very easy to use. Almost painfully easy to use.